# Weird error with using reader.GetGuid(0) with Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have this statement in my MySQL version:

```
Guid id = reader.GetGuid(0);
```

and it works. I have the same statement in other methods of my PostgreSQL version and they work too.  However, in one PostgreSQL method I had to substitute it to the following in order to make it work:

```
string idText = reader.GetString(0);
Guid id = Guid.Parse(idText);
```

Is this a bug with Npgsql?

EDIT: This error is thrown:

```
{System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type character to Guid
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDefaultDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 column)
```

Comment: what happens if you use GetGuid()? does it throw an exception? or does it give the wrong value? or...? what is the column type? note: the byte order of guids is notoriously problematic

Comment: @MarcGravell see my reply in the edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test, but Npgsql expects that column to be `uuid` and possibly does not support implicit conversion from text. You can read more about those type mappings here: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html